# Dataframe fillna with previous column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe contain `place_a, place_b, location`.

For some rows, location is NaN and I want to fill it with place_a + place_b text.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with joined columns by [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
s = df.place_a.str.cat(df.place_b, sep=',', na_rep='').str.strip(',')
df.location = df.location.fillna(s)
```

Or with `+` and separator:

```
s = (df.place_a.fillna('') + ',' + df.place_b.fillna('')).str.strip(',')
df.location = df.location.fillna(s)
```

Comment: First of all thank you.
But for some reason when place_a is NaN or place_b is NaN (both cant be NaN at the same row) it dosent work.
any help?

Comment: @LiamAshkenazi - because if add something to `NaN` output is `NaN`, both solution was changed for solving this problem. Btw, in question missing sample data, what you try (some code) and expected ouput, so there are downvotes.

Comment: sorry about that, still new to this platform.
Thank you.

Comment: @LiamAshkenazi - No problem, only I explain. [How to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)